# Install silverlight without bing and msn using group policy

Tags: script, group-policy, silverlight

I'm thinking about deploying Silverlight via group policy. However, I do not wish to make bing the search engine and MSN the homepage. Would performing a quiet install using `/q` be the answer to this or will it have to be done in a different way?

Comment: Maybe you can create an administrative package with the desired parameters with **msiexec /a "agent name.msi"**. You can follow this tutorial (start at third step applying your msi )  [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/34737-deploy-the-spiceworks-agent-with-a-gpo)

Comment: Why do you mistakenly believe that installing Silverlight requries you to set your search engine and homepage to those sites?  You could allow them to change them simply change them back with the same cript that installed Silverlight sliently.

Comment: There was an conflict with another GP that sets the homepage and searchengine which was flagging up security issues. this is the reason for that part of the question. this has been resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved by silently installing Silverlight using the Silverlight `msi` extracted from `Silverlight_x64.exe` using the following article - [Extracting Silverlight MSI from execuatble file](http://old.k2underground.com/blogs/johnny/archive/2012/09/13/deploying-the-silverlight-package-to-users-using-a-gpo.aspx)and then disabling Windows defender as it is not used anyways.